# Highest and lowest elements in trove TIntSet?

Tags: java, collections, sortedset, trove4j

[`TIntSet`](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/set/TIntSet.html) is "sorted set" by sense, i.e. it's elements have natural order.

Unfortunately, I can't find any methods similar to [`first()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#first--) and [`last()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#last--).

Is it possible to overcome this lack somehow?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the lib, but from your link there doesn't seem to be any mention to ordering. Why do you say it's ordered? Just because it contains Int? If that's the case, you are wrong: just because the domain has an ordering, it doesn't mean that one collection should use the natural one. Think of lists: 45->2 -> 99 is a valid, ordered list that doesn't follow the natural order.

Comment: I don't think set SHOULD be ordered, but I am sure I WANT it to be ordered. I WANT it, I NEED it, this is my demand. The question is how to satisfy it. I don't want to iterate over entire set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[fastutil](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/) is all ways better than Trove. There is [`IntSortedSet`](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/docs/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/ints/IntSortedSet.html) interface with `firstInt()` and `lastInt()` methods.

Answer (score 2):

TIntSet is not sorted (it's a hash set) so in order to find the min or max you would need to iterate all values.

Comment: `TIntHashSet` is a hash set. `TIntSet` is an interface.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any sorted implementation of that interface.

Comment: Correct. Trove does not currently support sorted sets.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think this set is sorted? It looks like it's not. It doesn't implement SortedSet or NavigableSet interfaces from JDK collections framework - there are no such methods there.

first() and last() methods are actually inherited from interface SortedSet https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html#first%28%29

Answer (score 0):

If you want first/last/cell/floor etc type of option then Tree based set is required and trove does not have anything like that. If you want to extend TIntSet to have such thing then

- one of the simple option can be maintaining sorted values in parallel int array and use that to serve first/last type of request, but this will required extra memory.
- another option is that you can use just one array for values but keep is sorted and use binary search to support map API. This can be little slow for get/put as compared to trove but you can save memory because trove has .5 loadfactor

So you can make decision based on trade off you want .